# Call function inside a lambda passed to a thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc4.8

I'm trying to create a object that can be given a function and its parameters to his constructor. This class will then call the given function inside a lambda that is instead passed to a thread. Something along the lines of

```
class worker {
public:
    template <class Fn, class... Args>
    explicit worker(Fn f, Args ... args) {
        t = std::thread([&]() -> void {
                f(args...);
        });
    }
private:
    std::thread t;
};

int main() {
    worker t([]() -> void {
        for (size_t i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            std::cout << i << std::endl;
    });

    return 0;
}
```

But I get the following error

```
error: parameter packs not expanded with '...': f(args...);
```

What am I doing wrong here? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What compiler?  Unrelated to your compiler error, but you should be aware that the code as written is going to almost certainly result in undefined behavior, because the lambda captures by reference, is moved into a thread, then the scope where the data is valid is left.

Comment: Looks like you have too many braces.

Comment: Your code does not compile as it is, there brackets everywhere, `t` is not declared, ...After cleaning, I have no problem compiling this, so you should provide an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TartanLlama There was more stuff inside the lambda leftover brace after cleaning it up

Comment: @Aram Add the compiler version to your question - This is clearly specific to gcc < 4.9 (it works with gcc 4.9). Upgrading your compiler would be the easiest way to fix this if you can.

Comment: @Aram for gcc4.8 you might use std::tuple to pass data to your wrapped function: `worker(Fn f, Args ... args) { std::tuple<Args...> p(argc...);   ....  f(p) .....`

Comment: It compiles fine with GCC 4.9. Can you try a newer compiler?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments, this compile fine with gcc-4.9 (and above), but if you need to use gcc-4.8 you can add parameters to the lambda in the `worker` constructor and pass the arguments via the `std::thread` constructor:

```
class worker {
public:
    template <class Fn, class... Args>
    explicit worker(Fn f, Args ...args) {
        t = std::thread([f](Args ...largs) -> void {
                f(largs...);
        }, std::move(args)...);
    }
private:
    std::thread t;
};
```

This will also create copy of the arguments in the lambda arguments, unlike the capture by reference you were using `[&]` that was probably incorrect in this case (see @Yakk comment).

Comment: Just a toy example I know but without joining or detaching that thread your main will make an unexpected call to `terminate()`...