# Move operations for a class with a thread as member variable

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, gcc4.8

I'm trying to expand with what some people helped me here [Call function inside a lambda passed to a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38614061/call-function-inside-a-lambda-passed-to-a-thread) so my worker class can support a move constructor and a move `operator=`, but I have the problem that my class is binding `this` by copy (or reference) to the thread so it can access the class values. Which are several `atomic<bool>`,  a `condition_variable` and a `mutex`.

But when I try to move it since the thread is bound to the other condition variable, `mutex` and `atomic`s, anything I do on it is not working. How can I fix this? 
Do I need to use a more complex object and move it around instead of a lambda so the thread can have a referenece to it? or is there another alternative.
As always help will be really appreciated :).

Here is a snippet (MWE) of the implementation.

```
class worker {
public:
    template <class Fn, class... Args>
    explicit worker(Fn func, Args... args) {
        t = std::thread(
            [&func, this](Args... cargs) -> void {
                std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
                while (true) {
                    cond.wait(lock, [&]() -> bool { return ready; });

                    if (terminate)
                        break;

                    func(cargs...);

                    ready = false;
                }
            },
            std::move(args)...);
    }

    worker(worker &&w) : t(std::move(w.t)) { /* here there is trouble  */ }

    worker &operator=(worker &&w) {
        t = std::move(w.t);
        terminate.store(wt.terminate);
        ready.store(wt.ready);
        return *this; 
        /* here too */
    }

    ~worker() {
        terminate = true;
        if (t.joinable()) {
            run_once();
            t.join();
        }
    }

    worker() {}

    void run_once() {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mtx);
        ready = true;
        cond.notify_one();
    }

bool done() { return !ready; }

private:
    std::thread t;
    std::atomic<bool> ready, terminate; // What can I do with all these?
    std::mutex mtx;                     //
    std::condition_variable cond;       //
};

int main() {
    worker t;
    t = worker([]() -> void { cout << "Woof" << endl; });
    t.run_once();
    while(!t.done()) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Sorry for the big dump of code.

Comment: Your issue is that you are moving an object that is in use in one thread out from under it in another. Question: why? Create the object dynamically and use smart pointers.

Comment: @kfsone Y-yeah that was what I was going with with my second question, wanted to know if there was something more elegant or that I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would 'fix' it by just saying `worker` is noncopyable and nonmoveable and leave it to the user of `worker` to store it as a `unique_ptr` if they want to move it around. There's nothing wrong with that at all. It's ordinary, actually.

If you absolutely want this class to be movable, you could use the Pimpl design pattern: make a `Worker::Impl` nested class which `worker` owns by `unique_ptr`. The `Impl` class would be noncopyable and nonmovable and basically be your current `worker` class. The lambda would have a pointer to the `Impl` class, not the `worker` class. The `worker` class would contain nothing except a `unique_ptr` to the `Impl` and functions that forward to the `Impl` class' functions, and the defaulted copy and move ctors/operators will just work properly for both classes (worker will be copyable but not movable, impl will be noncopyable and nonmovable).

Comment: Ok, I'll probably do the second one. Thanks.

Comment: @Aram Strongly recommend against it, I only put it there for completeness - to show that it is technically possible. The modern way to 'fix' this problem is to do nothing. Have a noncopyable/nonmovable class and let the user of the class handle it.

Comment: what are the cons of that approach if I might ask?

Comment: @Aram 1) If the user doesn't want to move the class they take the hit for the allocation/`unique_ptr` anyway. If you leave it to the user, they only take the hit if they need the hit. 2) It's an ordinary/expected aspect of c++ to potentially need to allocate classes if you want to pass around their ownership, in the case it's nonmoveable. Meaning, it's the c++ equiv of 'pythonic'... C++onic... lol. 3) Complexity. Why make something more complex to solve a problem that's not a problem.